# How to aggregate/group the data from one table and output the result as another table in PowerBI?

Tags: datatable, powerbi, powerquery, aggregation

I have a ****Raw Data** Table** as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

I want to group the data in the raw data table into the **Output Table** as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

Basically the output table is counting the number of student for each understanding level in different intake. May I know how should I get the output table from the raw data table? I'm still new in Power Query, any help will be greatly appreciated!

### This is what I have tried:

[image]

**Code:**

```
= Table.Group(Source, {"Intake"}, {
        {"Count_Little_Understand", each Table.RowCount(Table.SelectRows(_, each ([Topic 1] = "Little Understanding"))), Int64.Type},
        {"Count_General_Understanding", each Table.RowCount(Table.SelectRows(_, each ([Topic 1] = "General Understanding"))), Int64.Type}, 
        {"Count_Good_Understand", each Table.RowCount(Table.SelectRows(_, each ([Topic 1] = "Good Understanding"))), Int64.Type},
        {"Count_Fully_Understand", each Table.RowCount(Table.SelectRows(_, each ([Topic 1] = "Fully Understand"))), Int64.Type}
    })
```

I only able to get the table by individual Topic, not sure how to include other Topic appended below and also add another extra column to label the Topic as shown in my second screenshot. Hope to get some advice/help on how should I modified the code. Thank you/1

Comment: I added in what I have tried in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've rebuilt a similar but shorter table:

[image]

---

Now we first go into `Transform` (1), mark the Topic Cols (2) and `Unpivot Columns` (3).

[image]

---

Your table now looks like the following screenshot. Finally, we select the Value column (1), click on `Pivot Column` (2), select Employee Name (3).

[image]

---

****Result:****

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can `Unpivot` the `Topic` columns, then `Pivot` the `Understanding` column, using `Count` of *Employee Name* as the aggregate value.

Then simply reorder columns and sort rows, to suit the output you need:

```
#"Unpivoted Topic" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Raw Data Table", {"Employee Name", "Intake"}, "Topic", "Understanding"),
#"Pivoted Understanding" = Table.Pivot(#"Unpivoted Topic", List.Distinct(#"Unpivoted Topic"[Understanding]), "Understanding", "Employee Name", List.NonNullCount),
#"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Pivoted Understanding",{"Intake", "Topic", "Little Understanding", "General Understanding", "Good Understanding", "Fully Understand"}),
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Reordered Columns",{{"Topic", Order.Ascending}, {"Intake", Order.Ascending}})
```

Output:

[image]